# What netlink messages does docker set the container's interface name and how can it be changed?

Tags: docker, networking, network-programming, netlink

I am trying to set the name of the interface inside the a container via netlink. IE: `eth0` I want set to `mang0`.

Inside the container the root user gets permissions errors when they try to change the interface's properties:

```sh
root@d1df4b33fffc:/tmp/contbuild# ip link set eth0 down
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
root@d1df4b33fffc:/tmp/contbuild# ip link set eth0 name man0
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
root@d1df4b33fffc:/tmp/contbuild# ip link set eth0 alias man0
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

Outside the container, I see the set interface name command send in the kernel messages:

```
[ +11.115152] docker0: port 1(veth3a3f2f4) entered blocking state
[  +0.000007] docker0: port 1(veth3a3f2f4) entered disabled state
[  +0.000171] device veth3a3f2f4 entered promiscuous mode
[  +0.009358] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth3a3f2f4: link is not ready
[  +0.386448] eth0: renamed from vetheac9d07
[  +0.000259] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth3a3f2f4: link becomes ready
[  +0.000031] docker0: port 1(veth3a3f2f4) entered blocking state
[  +0.000002] docker0: port 1(veth3a3f2f4) entered forwarding state
```

I also see the corresponding veth pair on the host `veth3a3f2f4@if662`, but I cannot see the container's veth in any other netns (`ip netns show` is blank).

So I would like tp know:

- how is docker setting the name to `eth0` and is there a way to easily change it
- why can I not see the netns for the container and/or the container's interface from the host?

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around by running the container with `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN` and doing the following internally

```
ip link set dev eth0 down
ip link set dev eth0 name eth1
ip link set dev eth0 up
```